# SQL Script using sum(column1$)/count(distinct(column2person)

Tags: sql

trying to use sum and count distint function & not getting results

```
Column1    column2          column3   column4 (3dividedby2) 
personid    count distinct   sum$      sum$/count(distinct)
```

Above is the output i'm trying to get and what i see is this

```
Column1    column2          column3   column4 (3dividedby2) 
1234       20                20,000    20,000
```

instead i would want to see this

```
Column1    column2          column3   column4 (3dividedby2) 
1234       20                20,000    1,000
```

What am i doing wrong..

here is the query

```
select column1, count(distinct(column2)) as X, Sum(column3) as "COST"
, cost/ x as "Avg of column1 " 
from table.table1
group by column1;
```

thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot re-use aliases in the `select`.  Just repeat the expressions:

```
select column1, count(distinct column2) as X, Sum(column3) as cost,
       sum(column3) / count(distinct column2) as avg_column1
from table.table1
group by column1;
```

Comment: hi gordon, thanks.. first 10 mins at stack overflow.. thanks for the formatting.
Yes, i used your query. It does run, however, the output is still 20,000. What am i doing wrong? pls advise..

Comment: @peach_pie27 . . . That doesn't make sense.  Perhaps you have a typo or are misinterpreting the results.